the rank of the zero module over the zero ring is 1 or 0 or undefined?
Let $R=\{0\}$ be the zero ring and $M=\{0\}$ be the zero module over $R$ and this is the only $R$-module.
With the classical definitions (see following), we can see that both $\emptyset$ and $\{0\}$ are bases of $M$ over $R$. So I got confused, is it possible to use certain definitions of [spanning set] and [linearly independence] so that the rank of $M$ is well defined in this case?
Maybe it is not possible to unify it with the normal situation, because clearly $M\cong R$ so we should say $M$ is free of rank $1$, and $M=\langle \emptyset\rangle$ so we should say $M$ is free of rank $0$.

Here I use the following classical definitions:
Let $B\subset M$, then $\langle B \rangle$ is the intersection of submodules of $M$ that contains $B$. So that $\langle \emptyset\rangle=\{0\}$. We say $M$ is generated by $B$ if $M=\langle B\rangle$. We say $B$ is linearly independent if for any non-empty finite subset $\{b_1,\dots,b_n\}\subset B$, for all $r_i\in R$ s.t. $\sum_i r_i b_i=0$, we have $r_i=0$ for all $i$. So $\emptyset$ is linearly independent.
We say $B$ is basis of $M$ if $B$ is a linearly independent subset generating $M$. We say $M$ is free if it has a basis $B$. If $R\neq \{0\}$ then $R$ has a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ and the cardinality of every two bases of $R$ can be shown to be the same by tensoring with $R/\mathfrak{m}$ and reducing to the case of vector spaces, so the rank of $M$ is well defined if $M$ is free. Now the problem arises when $R$ is the zero ring.
What's the best way to deal with this case?

Update:  I found that this question asked the same thing. A quick search about "IBN" (Invariant basis number: every finitely generated free module over $R$ has a well defined rank) tells me all commutative ring except the zero ring has IBN, see this wiki page. So I guess we don't need to modify anything and this is just life.

Wikipedia remarks that the zero $0$-module is free of every rank. Which I guess makes sense, even if you give the free-object formulation. Then the false statement would be that free $0$-modules have exactly one rank.

By free-object formulation I mean that a module $M$ is free over the function $f:\kappa\to M$ if and only for all modules $N$ and for all functions $g:\kappa\to N$ there is exactly one morphism $u:M\to N$ such that $u\circ f=g$. It's clear that $M=0$ satisfies this for all $\kappa$ and $f$.

There is a sense in which the zero module $M$ over the zero ring $A$ has every rank that is immediate from the definitions. If you define a basis to be a linearly independent and spanning indexed family $(m_i)_{i\in I}$, then any family of elements of $M$ will be a basis (of course, such a family will consist solely of zeroes). On the other hand, if you define a basis to be a linearly independent and spanning set, then there are just two bases, namely $\varnothing$ and ${0}$.

Here is a different take. When $R$ is a commutative ring and $M$ is any finitely generated* $R$-module, the rank is well-defined as the function
$$\mathrm{rank}(M) : \mathrm{Spec}(R) \to \mathbb{N}, \quad \mathfrak{p} \mapsto \dim_{\kappa(\mathfrak{p})} M \otimes_{R} \kappa(\mathfrak{p}),$$
where $\kappa(\mathfrak{p}) = Q(R/\mathfrak{p})$ is the residue field at the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$. This definition is common in the special case that $M$ is locally free, in which case $\mathrm{rank}(M)$ is locally constant. If $M$ is free, then $\mathrm{rank}(M)$ is a constant function.
Notice that for a non-empty set $Y$ every function $\emptyset \to Y$ is constant, but the problem is that it has no unique value (unless $Y$ has just one element). Every element of $Y$ could be regarded as the value.
So we see that in order for the constant function $\mathrm{rank}(M)$ to be identified with a natural number, we need that $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is non-empty, which means that $R \neq 0$.
When $R = 0$, and thus $M = 0$, the rank is the (unique) function $\emptyset \to \mathbb{N}$. But it does not give us any natural number.
For the general theory of the rank function, we do not need to make any case distinction if $R = 0$ or not. We can always focus on a prime ideal and hence reduce to the case of a field. If there is no prime ideal, there is just nothing to work with, but that is no problem. See also here. And we can also work with the functions directly. For example, if $0 \to M' \to M \to M'' \to 0$ is an exact sequence of locally free $R$-modules, then $\mathrm{rank}(M) = \mathrm{rank}(M') + \mathrm{rank}(M'')$ holds as functions on $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$.
*For modules which are not finitely generated, just replace $\mathbb{N}$ by the large set of all cardinal numbers.

It seems that if $X$ is empty and $Y$ is nonempty, then the function $f:X\to Y$ does factor through $1$: let $y\in Y$; we can write $f$ as the composition of the unique function $X\to 1$ and the function $y:1\to Y$. Perhaps I am misunderstanding you.

@Joe Thanks, I have fixed the post. (I was thinking about the function with empty codomain, but this doesn't happen here.)

The free module of every rank over the zero ring is the zero module, so yes, as you say, the zero ring doesn't satisfy IBN.
An alternative way of restating "every commutative ring except the zero ring satisfies IBN," which is slightly more general and which might feel less unsatisfying, is that every ring admitting a homomorphism to a field satisfies IBN (because fields satisfy IBN, and we can extend scalars). Assuming the axiom of choice, the zero ring is the only commutative ring which does not admit such a homomorphism. This version of the statement has the benefit of remaining true in the absence of the axiom of choice (where we can't use Zorn's lemma to guarantee the existence of maximal ideals).

(+1) I often find that when a theorem fails for the trivial case, it has arguably not been stated correctly (at least from a conceptual point of view). Other examples: "every nonzero ring has a maximal ideal" $\leadsto$ "every proper ideal is included in a maximal ideal"; and "the continuous image of a nonempty compact space in $\mathbb R$ is bounded" $\leadsto$ "the continuous image of a compact space is compact".

By the way, you might want to clarify the statement "the zero ring is the only commutative ring which does not admit such a homomorphism" – this is provable in ZFC, but not in ZF. (I only bring this up because you mention the axiom of choice later in your answer.) If $R$ is a commutative ring with a homomorphism into a field, then $R$ must have a prime ideal by the first isomorphism theorem. But it is known to be consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that there exists a nonzero commutative ring without a prime ideal.

Why is that last sentence there? It seems off-topic to actually answering the question at hand.
